# Best video format / codec to optimise 'seeking' with Videogular

Tags: ionic2, html5-video, videogular

I am using the Videogular2 library within my Ionic 3 application. A major feature of the application is the ability to seek to different places within a video.

I noticed that some formats have very quick seek response, while others take seconds to get there, even if the video is in the buffer already - I assume this may depend on the decoding process being used.

What would the best compromise be in order to speed up seek time while still keeping the file size reasonably small so that the video can be streamed from a server?

EDIT
Well, I learned that the fact that my video was recorded in the mov format caused the seek delays. Any transcoding applied to this didn't help because mov is lossy and the damage must have been done already. After screen-capturing the video and encoding it in regular mp4, the seeking happens almost instantaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would the best compromise be in order to speed up seek time while
>   still keeping the file size reasonably small so that the video can be
>   streamed from a server?

Decrease key-frame distance when encoding the video. This will allow for building a full frame quicker with less scanning, depending on codec.

This will increase the file size if using the same quality parameters, so the compromise for this is to reduce quality at the same time.

The actual effect depends on the codec itself, how it builds intermediate frames, and how it is supported/implemented in the browser. This together with the general load/caching-strategy (you can control some of the latter via [media source extensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/)).